# Javascript complete addProperties function

Tags: javascript, properties

So here is the question that was asked on the exam today, This was the only one that I couldn't be able to complete, can anybody help please?

Complete function 'addProperties' so that the result is '4'.

```
function Team(){
    this.doctor1 = 'Foreman';
    this.doctor2 = 'Chase';

    this.countMembers = function(){
      var i = 0;
      for(var property in this){
        if(property.indexOf('doctor') != -1){ i++; }
      }
      return i; //result here must be 4
    };
}

function addProperties(object, props){
    for(var property in props){
        // your code
    }
}

var t = new Team();
addProperties(t, { 'doctor3': 'Cameron', 'doctor4': '13' });
t.countMembers();
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s4g2q6sr/ --> `object[property] = props[property];`.. It doesn't really make sense though to use that function to extend the properties of that object.. I would rather have implemented that function as prototype of Team.. Anyway, that's just it.

Answer (score 2):

Should be straight forward, just add the properties to the object

```
function addProperties(object, props){
    for(var property in props){
        object[property] = props[property];
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/o9qkd32o/)